# tensorflow: convert a list of tensor to ragged tensor with a fixed dim in a certain axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Suppose I have three numpy arrays with shape `(1,3)` and stack them into groups with shape `(2,3)` and `(1,3)`. Then I stack them with `tf.ragged.stack` to get a ragged tensor:

```
x1 = np.asarray([1,0,0])
x2 = np.asarray([0,1,0])
x3 = np.asarray([0,0,1])

group_a = np.stack([x1,x2])
group_b = np.stack([x3])


ac = tf.ragged.stack([group_a,group_b], axis=0)
```

I expect its shape to be `(2, None, 3)` but instead it's `(2, None, None)`. How do I get the desired shape? I'm using tensorflow 2.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `tf.ragged.stack` is creating a ragged_rank which equals to 2. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#ragged_rank_and_flat_values) for more information. You could explicitly define how to partition a ragged tensor like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x1 = np.asarray([1,0,0])
x2 = np.asarray([0,1,0])
x3 = np.asarray([0,0,1])

ac = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits(
    values=[x1, x2, x3],
    row_splits=[0, 2, 3])

print(ac.shape)
print(ac)
```

```
(2, None, 3)
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [[0, 0, 1]]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually answered by the official help:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#get_shape

```
x1=[[0, 1, 2]]
x2=[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 6]]

tf.ragged.constant([x1, x2], ragged_rank=1).shape
```

> ```
> Out[51]: TensorShape([2, None, 3])
> ```